# How to track a video click inside an iframe using google tag manager?

Tags: events, iframe, google-tag-manager

I want to track a vimeo video inside the following iframe:

```
<div class="embed-container"><iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/108361627?title=0&#038;api=1&#038;portrait=0&#038;badge=0" class="vimeoplayer" frameborder="0"  webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
```

I understand that I need to push data into the data layer to do this. How can I use the piece of code below to track a click on this iframe? Somewhere outside of the iframe I suppose? Can I give the .embed-container div an extra element with this event in some way?

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Video', 'Play', 'intro-video']);"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the Vimeo JavaScript API to listen for player events. When the player events fire,  call your GA tracking code.

Vimeo has a library call Froogaloop to help listen for events.

I've found that the vimeo.ga.js library is the best way to wire up GA to Vimeo. It works with Classic Analytics, Universal Analytics and Google Tag Manager.